# Open Graph: og:image display differences BETWEEN LINKEDIN AND FACEBOOK

Tags: facebook-opengraph, linkedin-api

It appears that Facebook and LinkedIn have differing standards for the og:image. 
On Facebook they advise that the image should be at least 200 x 200 pixels (square) see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)
However LinkedIn advise 180 x 110 pixels (rectangular) see [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/setting-display-tags-shares)

Is there a way to target an og:image to either Facebook or LinkedIn seperately? What's the best way of doing this?

I'm trying to create a default thumbnail for the website home page which will let users share the home page in a nice manner. At the moment LinkedIn is cropping my og:image though Facebook and Google+ are sharing it nicely.

Answer (score 10):

This ought to do it.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="image-180x110.jpg" /> <!-- 180x110 Image for Linkedin -->
<meta property="og:image:width" content="180" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="110" />
<meta property="og:image" content="image-200x200.jpg" /> <!-- 200x200 Image for Facebook -->
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
```

Comment: Did not do the trick for me. Facebook loads both images, but doesn't display the larger one when sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the server environment something like this may work.

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'LinkedInBot') !== false ? 'image-180x110.jpg' : 'image-200x200.jpg'); ?>" />
```